# Does onMouseOut event occurs when I remove in javascript the element the mouse is currently over?

Tags: javascript, events

I have an image. 
I attached onclick listener and onmouseout listener to it.
onclick listener does parent.removeChild(this) operation.
Image disappears. Nothing happens until I move my mouse. Then fires onmouseout handler.
Is it even possible?
And how, I assume not by propagation because there is nothing attached to onmouseout on parent elements.

Handlers:

```
    function ballMouseoutHandler(e) {
       event.stopPropagation();
       this.src = ballSrc;
       alert('mouse out!');
    }

   function ballMouseoverHandler() {
      this.src = ballInvSrc;
   }

   function ballClickHandler() {
     gameBalls.removeChild(this);
   }
```

Code adding image:

```
gameBalls = document.getElementById('balls-col');
var tmpBall = createBall();
gameBalls.appendChild(tmpBall);
tmpBall.addEventListener('click', ballClickHandler);
tmpBall.addEventListener('mouseover', ballMouseoverHandler);
tmpBall.addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) {ballMouseoutHandler(e);});

function createBall() {
   var ball = new Image();
   ball.src = ballSrc;
   ball.classList.add('ball');
   return ball;
}
```

It is a part of larger code. So what I have done so far is that I extracted the particular problem to separate smaller files. And it still looks as though the mouse out event was triggered.

Comment: Add your code, what you have done so far

Comment: Why don't you actually show the code instead of explaining it in words? What browser does it happen in?

Comment: I tested it in Safari

Comment: I wouldn't trust on the behaviour you are observing, but when it works it's fine. Do you have a particular problem?

Comment: Yes I have a problem that in real case scenario I expected the mouseOut handler not to be triggered after clicking the object which makes the object disappear. Because mouseOut in my case has only sense if this object is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. After some testing I can say that yes - removing an DOM Object from under the mouse pointer triggers the onmouseout event. Which if you think is quite logic because the move is relative and what counts is that mouse pointer was over the object and now it is out. :)

So what I had to do was to remove Event Listener **before** removing the Object.